# Email reference code behaves differently in different environments

Tags: email

I have faced some weird behavior as the above formula works for an instance but it doesn't work for the other(i.e. UAT and Production) because the reference code generated by the Salesforce under email section is different in both instances.

The reference code generated by Salesforce is different for each instance ?
If yes, how we can make the formula i.e generic for all the org's.

For example :-

```
QA reference code :-   [ ref:_00D18m8X._50014QYZT:ref ]

UAT reference code :-  [ ref:_00D18m8X._50014lQYZT:ref ]
```

Thanks in anticipation.

Thanks & Best,

Prashant Saxena

Comment: I see only difference of `l`, seems like a typo? Other it would have more letter difference.

Comment: From your explanation what I am understanding is you were expecting the email reference should be same in all orgs when you do hard code. If my guess is right you can not hard code that try to find a way to pull that by code if not still you need that email reference create a custom setting and paste the id and keep it as note when you are deploying every time in different org you had to copy paste the id

Comment: I am not hard-coding anything but the behavior of generating email reference code by salesforce is different in both the instances.Please see my below comment,it will be more clear to you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a threadId used in Email to Case. [Per SFDC Product Management](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006trk), the formula that generates a threadId is:

```
"ref:_" & LEFT($Organization.Id,5) & 
  SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(Organization.Id,11), "0", "" )& 
  "._" & LEFT(Id,5) & SUBSTITUTE(Left(RIGHT(Id,10), 5), "0", "") & 
 RIGHT(Id,5) & ":ref"
```

and, as you can see the orgId figures into the threadId construction - hence why you observe differences between QA and UAT

It is not clear why you would want the thread Id across orgs to be the same as in real SFDC it is not the same.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your comments. But my requirement is to clone the case along with it's emails.While cloning,I have replacing the reference code(parent to child) from a class  using a formula.So the issue is I need to use two different formula's for both QA and UAT because the email reference code generated by salesforce is different in both instances. Is there any way we can make a formula more generic which should be same in all the instances ?

Comment: But if the formula uses `$Organization.id` as above, it will work correctly across every org.